# Jenkins pipeline configuration in Pipeline configuration section

Tags: jenkins, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to setup "generic" build system and using Docker with Jenkins to build and run tests with pipeline.

I use wrapper script (pulled from repo) that contains most of the stuff docker needs. Only thing that changes is a tag for images.

How can I somehow define this tag in build configuration as an environment variable or similar which can be then passed to actual pipeline script.

Simplified script:

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage("Build test image") {
      dockerImage = docker.build("...", "--build-arg MYBRANCH=${SOMEVAR}")
    }
  }
}
```

So how I can set (per build config) `SOMEVAR`?

I could have per custom Jenkinsfile branch but eventually that will just end up with maintenance nightmare (I already now do have 7 branches to build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be defined by static in environment or dynamic in parameters. In case of parameters then you should provide values when run a build through interface or api.

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        SOMEVAR = "123"
    }
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'CHOICE_VAR', choices: ['1', '2', '3'], description: 'Type...')
        string(name: 'STRING_VAR', defaultValue: '', description: 'Type...')
    }
    stages {
        stage("Build test image") {
            dockerImage = docker.build("...", "--build-arg MYBRANCH=${env.SOMEVAR}")

            dockerImage = docker.build("...", "--build-arg MYBRANCH=${params.CHOICE_VAR}")
            dockerImage = docker.build("...", "--build-arg MYBRANCH=${params.STRING_VAR}")
        }
    }
}
```